# Epson SDK for iOS printing chinese

Tags: iphone, ios, printing, epson

I am facing a problem printing Chinese characters from my iOS application to my Epson Printer. When I'm trying to print Chinese, it's came out with question mark (???)

Has anyone of you managed to print Chinese on a TM-T88V with the epson SDK ? Or even has experience with the iOS espon SDK ?

Did anyone of your done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem here. The Epson support told me only the models bought in Asia supports the asian language.

So far I'm having trouble in printing any Chinese character with my TM T88-V printer and I'm thinking of getting one in Asia.

Quote from support:

> In Europe, Epson is offering only ANK (Alpha Numeric Katagana) models
>   of TM-printers. The Asian models (Japanese, simplified Chines,
>   traditional Chines, Korean, and South Asia) are supporting 2-byte code
>   while the ANK models not ! Based on the label you attached, I could
>   find out, the printer is an ANK model with Ethernet interface. An
>   Asian model you can only get at the Asian market.
>
> You can identify an Asian printer by using the command "GS I n" with
>   n= 0x45. It returns a string with a language information.